# Length Text Field

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I wrote this code below to get the length of a textfield and pop up an alert after it, it keeps ask me to declare the length in the `@interface`, how could I do that?

```
if ([myTextField length]<=0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should use [myTextField.text length]?

If this wasn't the problem then maybe you could post some codes and the error message to get more clarification ;D

Comment: thank u, i found the solution, it should be mytextfield.text.length